# tableView not showing data values

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to get my tableView to show content in its cells, but it doesn't and I don't know why.

Here is the code. I also have connected the table view to the viewcontroller through dataSource and delegate in the storyboard, so that's why there are not typed in the viewDidLoad() method.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    wordsArray = [Words(sectionName: "Example section", usedWords: ["aaaaa", "aaaaa", "aaaaa"])]

    tableView.alpha = 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return favCapitals.count
}

struct Words {
    var sectionName: String! = ""
    var usedWords: [String]! = []
}

var wordsArray: [Words] = []

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = wordsArray[indexPath.section].usedWords[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .black
    return cell
}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let sectionName = "Favourite Capitals"
    return sectionName
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to call the following methods before it listens to `cellForRowAt`:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
```

another common problem is that the frame of the table is not set (e.g. inside a UITableViewCell, with automatic dimensions). The table requires a frame before it gets cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tableView.reloadData() in the viewDidLoad Method.